# Memory Issues About Apps with a Single Page vs Multiple Pages

Tags: android, app-inventor

For anyone with experience in making apps with **App Inventor**: I am trying to make a complex app, and so far I thought about making different screens with vertical layouts, making one visible and the other invisible etc.

I plan to have a splash screen with images and sprites but that's it. The rest of the app will be text based. I'll have around 100 variables, 10 lists, 30 labels, 3 listviews, a notifier, a timer, around 40 procedures, a tinydb, a web component, and a canvas with 20 sprites.

Now, if I keep everything on one screen, will I have memory issues? Would it be better to build an app with multiple screens, opening one and closing the previous? I have a TinyDB already, and work with locally saved data, so passing information between screens isn't an issue, I just want to know which way would be better in terms of memory.

[I asked this in the App Inventor forum as well](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/x8yXwgsFVJY/kwan50TEilQJ), but I want to ask it here so more people will be able to see it and answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me recommend you to start with 2 screens: the splash screen and your main screen with the functionality. This approach keeps your blocks as small as possible and you can avoid redundancy.

More about redundancy see [Enis' tips](http://twodogapps.com/?page_id=686) and [Building apps with many screens](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/app-inventor-developers-library/kHEFtUiJsQM/obxo_CKizTcJ).

Later during development if the apps gets bigger and you get lagging issues with moving blocks or deleting blocks etc. you always can copy your main screen and split the functionality of the main screen into 2 screens then.

[How to copy screens](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/app-inventor-developers-library/kHEFtUiJsQM/obxo_CKizTcJ) by Scott and a [video](http://amerkashi.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/ai-screen-manipulation/) by Hossein